# SKSpriteNode in array change image

Tags: arrays, swift3, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I put few SKSpriteNode in SKSPriteNode Array in didMove(to view:SKView) using

```
enumerateChildNodes(withName: "//*") { (node, stop) in
    if let spriteNode = node as? SKSpriteNode{
            if let nodeName = node.name{
                if nodeName.hasSuffix("Button"){
                    self.buttons.append(spriteNode)

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and now using a result from my NSCoding I would like change my buttons image

```
    for node in self.buttons{
        if let name = node.name{
            if name.hasSuffix("Button"){
                let letter = name.replacingOccurrences(of: "Button", with: "", options: .regularExpression)
                if let number = self.gameResult[letter]{
                    switch number{
                    case 1:
                        node = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "\(letter)Button-Bronze")
                    case 2:
                        node = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "\(letter)Button-Silver")
                    case 3:
                        node = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "\(letter)Button-Gold")
                    default:
                        node = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "\(letter)Button-Bronze")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

It appears that all node in array are let and I cannot change images in my SKSpritNode buttons.

How can I do that?

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 1):

Any time you enumerate over a collection (`for node in array` etc), the property used for enumerating is automatically a `let`. The whole collection itself is also immutable, because changing the collection whilst enumerating over it could have unforeseen consequences.

copy the nodes to a new array, changing the properties of the nodes as you desire and then swap the arrays afterwards.

Is there a reason why you can't change the node's images via `enumeratechildNodes(withName:`?

Comment: Thank you. New array seems to be a super solution for my problem. Regarding enumaratechildNodes I tried but spriteNode as? SKSpriteNode has let as well. How you will do that in enumarate? Thank you for all help

Comment: You can put something like `var myNode = spriteNode` (assuming `spriteNode` is the enumerating variable) to give yourself a mutable spritenode.

Comment: Amazing! Working like a charm. Super. Thank you very much